# For a split method involving arrays (in java), when do "" occur?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, split

The signature for the split method is:
public String[] split(String regex)
The following examples assume that test String s has been created and that the String sp array have already been declared:
`String s = "Hello again", sp[];`

Example:

`sp = s.split("a|g");`

How the book said the answer to this is:
`"a|g" means a or g (same as [ag]), sp[0] = "Hello ", sp[1] = "" sp[2] = "", sp[3] = "in", (notice the elements of zero length)`

Can somebody explain the above example and why sp[1] and sp[2] will have "". Also what does it mean when a|g is same as [ag]

Comment: Between `a` and `g` there is nothing -> empty string, and same thing between the following `g` and `a`.

Comment: In a previous example, it showed:
sp = s.split(“e|g”); 
// “e|g” means either ‘e’ or ‘g’, sp[0] = “H”, sp[1] = “llo a”,
// sp[2] = “ain”

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you had X instead of 'a' and 'g' in your string: "Hello XXXin" and you split on "X" (because in our example 'X' is *either 'a' or 'g'*, that is "a|g"). There are three consecutive Xs in there, with nothing between them.

```
H e l l o  X X X i n
H e l l o  ^ ^ ^ i n
----------- - - ----
```

(Double spacing to help visualize where the split happens)

Hence you get the two empty strings between them.

About your comment, let's see what happens when X, instead, is either 'e' or 'g'

```
H X l l o  a X a i n
H ^ l l o  a ^ a i n
-   --------   -----
```

As you can see, no empty spaces between two occurrences of X, because there are no consecutive Xs, So you get three proper strings: "H", "llo a" and "ain".

---

About your question on what does it mean that the regexes "a|g" and "[ag]" are equivalent, the first mean "an 'a' OR a 'g'", the second means "any character that is part of a set composed solely of the characters 'a' and 'g'". I hope you appreciate that those two statements are logically equivalent.

Comment: Oh okay. Can you explain why this problem (below) will not include any "" in comparison to the problem above?

sp = s.split(“e|g”); // “e|g” means either ‘e’ or ‘g’, sp[0] = “H”, sp[1] = “llo a”,
// sp[2] = “ain”

Comment: @Cypexe edited my answer to explain that as well.

Comment: Got it! Thank you

Comment: @Cypexe I also added an explanation for the equivalence between `a|g` and `[ag]`. But please for the future limit your questions to one per post.

Answer (score 0):

The split regex consumes and splits on what’s matched. In this case it splits on either an `"a"` or a `"g"`.

Here’s the input with brackets around the matches and the line underneath with the result aligned to the input:

```
 Hello (a)(g)(a)in
"Hello ","","","in"
```